# Llamar a función que se pasa como cadena en parametros

Tags: javascript

Este es el trozo de código que utilizo para construir mi paginador, donde funcion es el string con el nombre de la funcion de busqueda,  :

```
function construyePaginacion(funcion, filasporpagina, total, empieza, filas){
    
    var paginaSeleccionada = (parseInt(empieza) / filasporpagina) + 1;
        
    btnPrimero.onclick = function() {
        paginaSeleccionada = parseInt(primerhueco.innerHTML);       
        buscarEspacios((paginaSeleccionada-1)*filasporpagina);
    };
    
    btnSegundo.onclick = function() {
        paginaSeleccionada = parseInt(segundohueco.innerHTML);      
        buscarEspacios((paginaSeleccionada-1)*filasporpagina);
    };
    
    btnTercero.onclick = function() {
        paginaSeleccionada = parseInt(tercerhueco.innerHTML);   
        buscarEspacios((paginaSeleccionada-1)*filasporpagina);
    };

}
```

Quiero que el paginador sirva para otro tipo de entidades, por eso quiero sustituir los buscarEspacio() por el parametro funcion.  Por ejemplo, si funcion es 'buscarGrupo' (el parametro funcion de construyePaginacion), como haría uso de funcion?

Comment: Sustituye `buscarEspacios` por `funcion` dentro de la función `construyePaginacion` y cuando la invoques hazlo sin comillas, es decir, por ejemplo, así:  `construyePaginacion(buscarEspacios, "1", "3", "2", "1")`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript permite pasar funciones como parámetros, que serán objetos de la clase `Function`. Esto es muy útil para, por ejemplo, retrasar ejecuciones :

```js
function miFuncion(p) {
  console.log('Función ejecutada, recibiendo parametro:',p);
}
console.log('está declarada: ',miFuncion instanceof Function)
console.log('en un segundo se ejecutará miFuncion');
setTimeout(miFuncion, 1000, 'patito');
```

Lo que quieres, sin embargo, es pasar el nombre de la función a ejecutar, lo que también es posible pero crea limitaciones y complica todo un poco: La función a llamar debe ser global o ser parte de un objeto al que la función que llamará tenga acceso. En otro caso, no hay forma de llamarla:

```js
function enGlobal() {
  console.log('funcion global');
}


// Esto es una estrategia típica para no contaminar el espacio global, 
// declarando nuestro código dentro de un contexto que se ejecutará inmediatamente.
// Es un ejemplo de clausura
(function() {

  function noGlobal() {
    console.log('función no global');
  }
  
  const test = { noGlobal } ;
  
  function ejecutaFuncionGlobal(param) {
    window[param]();
  }
  
  function ejecutaFuncionEnTest(param) {
    test[param]();
  }
  
  ejecutaFuncionGlobal('enGlobal');
  ejecutaFuncionEnTest('noGlobal');

})();
```

Esto funciona porque toda función declarada en el contexto global, es automáticamente una propiedad del objeto global: `window` en los navegadores, global en `NodeJS`